# HTML5 video not working on IE and Safari

Tags: html

I have following HTML5 video tag.  It works fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE 9 and Safari, not video at all.  Any ideas??

```
<video controls="true">
  <source src="ronald.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="ronald.webm" type="video/webm" />

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this about IE9 http://geekswithblogs.net/Wessty/archive/2011/03/13/ie9-and-the-mystery-of-the-broken-video-tag.aspx

Comment: Is your server using the correct MIME types for the MP4 video files? Browsers can be very picky about these things.

Comment: I checked MIME types in IIS and could find .mp4 (video/mp4) and .webm (video/webm).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="ronald.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="ronald.webm" type="video/webm" />
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Comment: I checked with the following code but still no luck.

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">

Comment: Just noticed I didn't have a DOCTYPE tag on the page, so I added <!DOCTYPE html> on the top and now the video comes in IE but still not in Safari.

Comment: it is work in my safari browser  add                           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">